# How to use hexadecimal values in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, teradata

Only Teradata.

I am testing `charhexint`. I want to find all records that have word "robin" (which is 0072006F00620069006E in hex) in the name1 field. Why the following returns no records?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE CHAR2HEXINT(name1)  LIKE '%0072006F00620069006E%'
```

**P.S.**
When I do

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE name1  LIKE '%robin%'
```

I get a lot of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

Check the character set of `name1`, your search string is for UNICODE, but the column might be LATIN:

```
WHERE CHAR2HEXINT(name1)  LIKE '%726F62696E%'
```

If the column is defined as NOT CASESPECIFC and your session is in Teradata mode any comparison (including LIKE) will be not casesensitive, thus returning Robin, ROBIN, etc., too. Of course CHAR2HEXINT returns different values for `a`and `A`:

```
WHERE CHAR2HEXINT(UPPER(name1))  LIKE '%0052004F00420049004E%'
```